# Remove old bathroom faucet

Tags: faucet

Help! I am trying to replace the old ugly faucets in my house,  which was built in 2003. Only I can't figure out how to remove the old faucet.  It does not look like what is shown in all of the online videos I've looked at.  I've unscrewed all I can see to unscrew,  but am stuck.  Anyone familiar with this, who knows what I can do? Pictures attached.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you removed the water spout?

Comment: Are you sure that round ring under the brass ring doesn't turn?  Any notches in it? Can you grab it with a pair of channelocks?

Comment: So, I finally did.  I figured out this is a 'bottom mounted faucet'. I had to put a 5.5mm allen wrench into the hole in the faucet to unscrew it. Now I an trying thi figure out how to remove the rusted c clips.  This is a horrible faucet design

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you need to:

- remove all possible trim and rings from the top.
- unscrew a hex set-screw from the underside (see blue arrow) that clamps the unit to the deck by pressing up against the "hold-down plate" (see yellow arrow).
- once loose, the hold down plate will slide away from the faucet body, allowing the faucet body to drop out from the deck, striking you in the nose, eye, or lip/front tooth.

[image]